# Sorting php array using column value and printing to a table

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am querying sql and response feedback is as follows in an array format stored in `$result_rows`,

**print_r($result_rows)** - shows the following 2D array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee_zipcode]   => 70062
            [employee_name]      => Carter Jr
            [employee_address]   => 472 Shadowmar Drive Kenner, LA 
            [employee_id_series] => 6144

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [employee_zipcode]  =>  70062
            [site_name]          => Carter Sr
            [address]            => 472 Shadowmar Drive Kenner, LA 
            [employee_id_series] => 6144
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [employee_zipcode]  => 29210
            [site_name]         => Claude 
            [address]           => 2308 Wexford Way Columbia, SC 
            [employee_id_series]=> 6144

        )


)
```

The above dynamic result is obtained when I query `employee_id_series` by `6144`

**I am confused on how to sort down the array and print it to a html table in this format**

*Desired Result:*

```
Emp                 Emp     Emp
Zipcode_Series      Name    Address

70062_6144
70062_6144          Carter  472 Shadowmar Drive Kenner, LA 

29210_6144          Claude  2308 Wexford Way Columbia, SC
```

NOTE: `sorting_joining` is done based on `employee_zipcode` value,

whose same `value(70062)` is cross checked through out the array.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Tried using foreach,while...few but my scenario isn't working ,totally blown brains trying few ways,everything failed.

Comment: did you try adding your query `group by employee_zipcode` ?

Comment: Dont want to sort in sql ,php array need to compare those 70062 with input query 6144 and dump those matches in a single table row

Answer (score 1):

Once you use `usort` that @Crayon mentioned. You could use another associative array to print the result that you want. It's a rough version. Hope it help.

```
usort($result_rows, 'cmp');
function cmp($row1, $row2) {
    if ($row1['zipcode'] == $row2['zipcode']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($row1['zipcode'] > $row2['zipcode']) ? -1 : 1;
}

//Create the printing_results as an associative array to keep the same zipcode together and increase the count.
$printing_results = array();
foreach ($result_rows as $result) {
    $zipcode = $result['zipcode'];
    $result['cnt'] = 1;
    if (!isset($printing_results[$zipcode])) {
        $printing_results[$result['zipcode']] = $result;
    } else {
        $printing_results[$result['zipcode']]['cnt'] = $printing_results[$result['zipcode']]['cnt'] + 1;
    }
}

//For each associative array, print zipcode for other records and print all details on the last record.
foreach ($printing_results as $key => $printing_result) {
    $cnt = $printing_result['cnt'];
    for ($i=0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
        echo "\n".$printing_result['zipcode'];
    }
    print "\t".$printing_result['name']."\t".$printing_result['address'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code,excellent way to go , but there is a fundamental issue, row s in realtime sql response are not fixed 1 or 2 or 10 so it need to compare for all the rows not just between $row1 and $row2 , can u suggest a genric instead ?

Comment: The compare function compares any 2 items in array, not just row1 and row2. I might have not be clear about using the variable names. You could change them to function cmp($a, $b)

Comment: Here is the updated one. http://goo.gl/qpx58s and the reference for usort function http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use [usort](http://www.php.net/usort) to custom sort by the 2nd level array element:

```
usort($result_rows, function($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['employee_zipcode'] == $b['employee_zipcode'])
        return 0;
    else if ($a['employee_zipcode'] > $b['employee_zipcode'])
        return -1;
    else 
        return 1;
});
```

from there.. i'm not sure why you really want/need to merge `employee_zipcode` and `employee_id_series`.. seems better that you should leave them separate and just concat in presentation but I assume that's something trivial for you to do if you *really* want that..

> Dont want to sort in sql ,php array need to compare those 70062 with
>   input query 6144 and dump those matches in a single table row

Is there any particular reason you *need* to show multiple `70062_6144` in a single row like that? If not, you can just [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) the sorted array.

Comment: adding to the above code - goo.gl/v0Uq8g can u suggest  how to solve the logic if the row count is unknown , a genric way for X no of rows